# How do I get an element to appear once it has been selected from a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu that has school subjects listed. I also have a countdown timer for each subjects test date (many subjects share a date). I want to make it so that when the user selects the subject, the right countdown timer appears without the page refreshing.

Right now I have this working using PHP: I have 9 different countdown timer made in JavaScript (I used [this tutorial from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown)) and 9 separate PHP files like this:

```
 $newSubject = $_GET["chooseSubject"];
if ($newSubject == "Math" OR $newSubject == "Chemistry") {
echo '<p id="subjectSet1"></p>';
echo '<p class="dates">October 16. 2019 klo 9:00</p>';
}
```

I have a button that redirects to a page that then shows the correct countdown timer.

However, I'm looking to achieve something like this:

https://yle.fi/aihe/artikkeli/2019/05/15/ylioppilaskokeiden-pisterajat-kevat-2019

Under the "Ylioppilaskokeiden pisterajat, kevät 2019" there is a select menu, and when you choose a subject it automatically shows the correct table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where project design comes into play. If you expect your dropdown set to be small, you can simply render all of the content on page-load and then use JS/CSS to show/hide each block of content on change of the dropdown.

Alternatively, if you are expecting a larger dataset this could potentially affect your page load times and also make it longer for the browser to render the data (even when it is in a hidden element). In this situation I would look into using AJAX and load in content when you click on a section instead. This is slightly more complex but is;

1. A good learning exercise
2. More efficient in the long-term

EDIT:
If you're wanting to go down the show/hide route. This is simple enough using jQuery. There are a few options you could take however I would suggest toggle as a start - [see docs here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

For AJAX, this will take a bit more reading into. I would also suggest using jQuery's `ajax` function - [see docs here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings)

Comment: Any useful links you could provide?

Comment: Added some starting points for you. But it really depends on your project and personal preference.